# How to get JSON property value without parsing, using regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to get part of string using a regex but I'm not that experienced and I cannot achieve the goal.

**The full string:**

`{"A":"tex","x":[["ACS",0.00,"ol"]],"y":8}`

I want to get the `y`value.

I'm trying something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"y\":(.+?)}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);

while (matcher.find()) {
     String y = matcher.group(1);
     Log.d(TAG, "getYValue - matcher: " + y);
}
```

I also tried using substring, but the string can change in length, so y position will change according to the string.

Please, elaborate response for my understanding, I don't know much about regex.

Comment: What problem are you observing with the code you have tried?

Comment: Your current implementation works right? https://ideone.com/3mGIgG What is the question?

Comment: I can't match value. `"y":8}`. Regex isn't finding `8`.

Comment: i'm not regex guru but your code does find 8. i do not see problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### warning

Hope you are aware of the danger of using regex to parse formal grammar (for example you could have multiple `"y"` properties in your json).

Any reason why you don't want to parse it?

### regex attempt

From [json.org](https://www.json.org/) spec (see below) you have to accommodate whitespaces around the value and also "not-commas" and "not-whitespaces" for the value and this will work only for **simple values** (as in **no objects** or **json arrays**).

Threfore your regex pattern would be safer with (omitting outer quotes of Java String):

`\{.*\"y\"\s*:\s*([^,\s]+).*?\}`

or if you know it is a number you are looking for you can do better:

`\{.*\"y\"\s*:\s*(\d+).*?\}`

See it in action [here](https://regexr.com/4n1ol).

[image]

Comment: I'm not that experienced, later I've just realized that it's better to parse JSON, as I said in my answer. BTW, I appreciate your good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative and probably better way, is creating a JSONObject from json string and get its value.

```
try {
      JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
      int y = jObject.getInt("y");
      Log.d(TAG, "getYValue - JSON: " + y);
} catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```